# Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, crystal-reports, desktop-application

Using Visual Studio 2019, I have created a Crystal Reports .Net Executable and it runs fine on the PC that it was built on. However, when I copy the exe application to another system and try to run it, I get the following error message:

```
 Message="An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details. The 
 error is: Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms, 
  Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its 
  dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."
```

Comment: Did you embed the assembly into the program? Use `copy if new`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to install the SAP Crystal Reports Runtime for .NET Framework using their msi file.
Or perhaps you installed using the 64-bit version while your app is 32-bit or vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you deploy your .Net EXE with the SAME Crystal runtime engine you used in Visual Studio.

```
Version=13.0.4000.0
```

That version changes based on the version of the Crystal runtime engine you use/deploy.